# How to renew SSL certificates for Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, debian, ssl-certificate

I'm supporting two plants that are running a labview application, that is basically a black box and I can't modify, which is using a postgresql 9.2 database to which it connects using SSL. All is running on Debian 7.2. The company that built the system no longer exists.

```
Host:Port: 10.10.101.10:5432 (SSL require)
DB-Name: PPCDB (User: postgres)

postgres-Meldung:
SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

I have root, I've tried disabling SSL in postgres which works partially allowing the labview application to start, however none of the software clients work which is obviously a problem.

Can anyone guide me on how to renew the certificates so that the application will be able to connect to the database? Again, the application I can not modify, I can only stop it and start it. Is it even possible?

Comment: For the server ssl certificate locations are configured in `postgresql.conf`. For the client (if client certs are needed) there are default locations, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html